# Super dense edge-transitive graphs

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory

Let $G$ be a regular $n$-vertex graph which is edge transitive.  How large can the degrees of $G$ be if it is not a complete $r$-partite graph?

The best I can do is about $n/2$ by considering two disjoint cliques of the same size.  A relatively easy argument shows that any $n$-vertex edge transitive graph with degree $n-o(\sqrt{n})$ must be complete $r$-partite, so one can not hope to do better than this.  I'd be interested to see improvements to either of these two bounds, and in particular in knowing whether there can exist such graphs with degrees $n-o(n)$.

Comment: What if you remove a perfect matching from $K_{2n}$?

Comment: Unfortunately that is a complete r-partite graph (where each part has size 2).

Comment: Small comment: since you want to beat $n/2$, the graph cannot be bipartite and so must be vertex-transitive.

Comment: How about the complement of $K_m\square K_m$? It has $n=m^2$ vertices and valency $(m-1)^2$ and is edge-transitive.

Comment: @verret that is exactly what I'm looking for!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take $G=\overline{K_m\square K_m}$, the complement of the Cartesian product of two copies of the complete graph on $m$ vertices. It has $m^2$ vertices, valency $(m-1)^2$ and is edge-transitive. (In fact, we have $\mathrm{Aut}(G)=S_m\wr S_2= (S_m\times S_m)\rtimes S_2$.)